# Not getting any details when running "Install-Update Package" through Sitecore Powershell Module remoting service for my sitecore instance

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-install-framework

I am running a Powershell Script using Sitecore Powershell Module remoting service to install .update packages from my host to a remote Sitecore instance but I am not getting any details back on the package installation....

this is my script:

```
Param(
[string]$SitecoreInstanceUri = "http://SitecoreTestInstance",
[string]$SitecorePackagePath = "C:\test\AllLocalUpdatePackages",
[string]$UpgradeAction = "Upgrade",
[string]$InstallMode = "Install",
[string]$SitecoreAdminUser = "admin",
[string]$SitecoreAdminUserPassword = "b",
[array]$UpdatePackages = @("ASF.Main.Core")
)

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
import-Module -Name SPE

#find the real path of the package based on the partial package path given  
$UpdatePackages | ForEach-Object -Process {

try {

    $pattern = $_ + "*"
    $packagePath = ($SitecorePackagePath | Get-ChildItem -Include $pattern - 
    Recurse) 

    $parameters = @{"Path" = $packagePath.FullName; "UpgradeAction" = 
    $UpgradeAction; "InstallMode" = $InstallMode }
    $session = New-ScriptSession  -Username $SitecoreAdminUser -Password 
    $SitecoreAdminUserPassword -ConnectionUri $SitecoreInstanceUri -Timeout 
    300
    #Install Package
    Write-verbose "Installing Sitecore update Package 
    $($packagePath.FullName) on $($SitecoreInstanceUri)" -verbose

    $jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

        try {
            Install-UpdatePackage -Path $(($using:parameters).Path) - 
            UpgradeAction $(($using:parameters).UpgradeAction) -InstallMode 
            $(($using:parameters).InstallMode) | Select-Object -Property 
            LongDiscription

            $package = ($using:parameters).Path
        }
        catch {
            $errorMessage = $_
            Write-Verbose "Following error occured when installing 
            $($package) : $($errorMessage)"
        } 

    } -AsJob -Verbose 

    #Query the job status to see if the item install is done 
    Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose                 


}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-verbose $ErrorMessage
    Write-Host "Issue Occured with this particular package"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a parameter on your `Write-Verbose` calls. If you look at the documentation (https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting), the example calls `Write-Verbose` like this:

```
Write-Verbose "Hello from the other side" -Verbose 4>&1
```

You can make this neater by overriding the `Write-Verbose` function in your script block like this:

```
Invoke-RemoteScript -ScriptBlock {
    function Write-Verbose {
        param([string]$Message)
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Verbose -Message $Message -Verbose 4>&1
    }

    Write-Verbose "Hello from the other side"
    "data"    
    Write-Verbose "Goodbye from the other side"
} -Session $session
```

Unfortunately the link to the information about `4>&1` is missing, but you can try that.